# How we do as odd header is the chapter-title, and the even header is the title of the thesis-title?

Tags: header-footer, thesis, books

I am writing my thesis in report class but I figured out that my title chapters (thesis-title) are not appearing on the headers. My goal is to realize this layout for a thesis.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.sx! Have a look at our [starter page](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Do you specify the "twoside" option? Without a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) your question is difficult to answer.

Edit:

```
\documentclass [twoside, 12pt]{report}
   
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\title{My Title}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[CO]{My Title}
\fancyhead[CE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage} 

\begin{document}
\chapter{My Chapter 1}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

Comment: \documentclass[12pt]{report}

Comment: thank you it is working.